# How to start using a downloaded plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, plugins, installation, jquery-chosen

I recently downloaded two plugins, https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen and https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll. I extracted the files. Now what? I'm guessing for a start I have to move the files somewhere. I'm just trying to figure out how to 'install' them into my app. There are tutorials for how to use the plugins after they're installed, but none on the actual installation.

I have a rails 4.0.10 app, if that matters.

Comment: you can move the files in `app/aseests/chosen/files` and `/app/assets/fredwn` or you can put them in the `vender`

Comment: @MZaragoza And after that I can just start using them?

Comment: I have not read there documentation but as long as you add the js and css links to your layout you should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails way of doing it would be to put any 3rd party lib under `vendor/assets`. JS files in the `javascripts` directory and CSS files in the `stylesheets`.  The you need to require the files in either the `application.js` or `application.css` files.  Doing this will ensure that the files get compiled and minified within the Asset Pipeline of your application.

EDIT #1:

Information about organizing application assets http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

EDIT #2:

I highly recommend using the [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/) framework when using 3rd party libs.  Makes managing assets much easier.

Comment: So by 3rd party lib do you mean files that aren't javascript or css? In this case, the chosen plugin doesn't appear to have any javascript **or** css files, only sass, json, coffee and a few other types. What would I do in that situation?

Comment: No.  I mean any assets (javascript, stylesheet, etc) that is not native to the Rails Framework, or is not provided by a Gem.

Comment: Also, SASS is is CSS and Coffeescript and JSON are Javascript. http://sass-lang.com/ http://coffeescript.org/

Comment: Ah, I see. So to be clear, Javascript files in the vendor/assets/javascripts folder, CSS in the vendor/assets/stylesheets folder, and all other files just in the vendor/assets folder?

Comment: Depends on what those "other" files are.  In reality, you can stick those files anywhere, so long as you require them in the associated application.js or application.css file, or include them in your layout file with `stylesheet_link_tag` or `javascript_include_tag`.  I just showed you the Rails conventional way of dealing with 3rd party assets.

Comment: For example, there's a package.json, a Gemfile, a Gemfile.lock, etc.

Comment: @user3739453 it appears you pulled down the repository source code and not the complied versions of the libraries.  I recommend you refer to the developers documentation as to location of the compiled libraries.

Comment: Ohh yeah you're right, I was looking at the wrong download, I apologize. The plugin files however contain ".jquery"s and ".proto"s. Do you know what to do with those? Their "type" reads "javascript" so do I just treat them like any other javascript files?

Comment: One is a library for JQuery implementations and the other is for Prototype implementations.

Comment: So if I'm using JQuery I should require the .jquery files and ignore the .proto's?